# get ion-radio in the center

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I'm currently working a privacy page in html with Ionic 3 and my output should be like this : [image: OUTPUT]

Right now with my code, this is what I get: [image: MY CODE]

This is my code:

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="flag1">
  <ion-grid item-center style="border-style: none">
  <ion-row item-center style="border-style: none">
  <ion-col col-4>
  <ion-item style="border-style: none" item-center>
      <ion-radio color="dark" [value]="true"></ion-radio>
      <ion-label class="radio-text">Si</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-4>
  <ion-item style="border-style: none" item-center>
      <ion-radio item-left color="dark" [value]="false"></ion-radio>
      <ion-label item-center class="radio-text">No</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-list>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
.radio-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-justify: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And need as well to remove that annoying black bar, already tried with border 0 but didn't work, anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: it will be easy to help you with stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qz2jun (put your code fork it and post link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center add `<ion-col col-2></ion-col>` before radio buttons:

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="flag1">
  <ion-grid item-center style="border-style: none">
  <ion-row item-center style="border-style: none">
  <ion-col col-2></ion-col>
  <ion-col col-4>
  <ion-item style="border-style: none" item-center>
      <ion-radio item-left  color="dark" [value]="true"></ion-radio>
      <ion-label class="radio-text">Si</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-4>
  <ion-item style="border-style: none" item-center>
      <ion-radio item-left color="dark" [value]="false"></ion-radio>
      <ion-label  class="radio-text">No</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-list>
```

To style it square use:

```
.radio-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-justify: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.radio-md .radio-icon, .radio-wp .radio-icon{
border-radius: unset !important;
}
.input-wrapper {
  -webkit-flex:  0!important;
    -ms-flex: 0!important;
    flex: 0!important; 
}
.item-md .radio-md[item-left], .item-md .radio-md[item-start] {
     margin: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: testing on ionic serve, and this is my output: https://imgur.com/a/T9MX8WE

Comment: try `border-radius: unset !important;`

Comment: yh but Si and No disappeard and there is still the black line

Comment: `.list-md .item-block .item-inner{
  border-bottom: none !important;
}`

Comment: almost perfect, no text appears

Comment: see in F12 what happen to text

Comment: removing this text appears: .input-wrapper { -webkit-flex:  0!important;-ms-flex:0!important;flex: 0!important;}

Comment: if my answer help you I will be happy if you mark as answer

Comment: last question, this is the output: https://imgur.com/a/F2NKtnf how can I add some space? and they are not centered I'm trying on responsive device on chrome